# Below is json data m trying to read from text file through java program. facing parsing error

Tags: java, json, parsing

> Json data from text file

```
{"projectkey":"proj1"} 
    {"projectkey":"proj2"}
    {"projectkey":"proj3"}
```

> java code to read the json objects from above file

```
//package crunchify.com.tutorials;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * @author Crunchify.com
 * How to Read JSON Object From File in Java?
 */

public class DemoJson {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("W:\\FileDemo\\jsoninput.txt"));
```

> A JSON object. Key value pairs are unordered. JSONObject supports java.util.Map interface.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
```

> A JSON array. JSONObject supports java.util.List interface.

```
String projectkey = (String)jsonObject.get("projectkey");

// An iterator over a collection. Iterator takes the place of Enumeration in the Java Collections Framework.
// Iterators differ from enumerations in two ways:
// 1. Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.
// 2. Method names have been improved.
Iterator<String> keys = (Iterator<String>) jsonObject.keySet();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
String key= keys.next();
if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
System.out.println(jsonObject);
}
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are facing?

Comment: A map won't make sense here as the key would be the same `projectkey` and for a list your json elements in the file would have to be in an array `[{"projectkey":"proj1"} , ...]`

Comment: I think it should be `jsonObject.keySet().iterator();` instead of `jsonObject.keySet();`.

Comment: @sneha I have posted an answer let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

your `JSON` is incorrect , It should be

```
[
   {
      "projectkey":"proj1"
   },
   {
      "projectkey":"proj2"
   },
   {
      "projectkey":"proj3"
   }
]
```

storing the above JSON into string (as of reading from file)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "[\r\n" + 
                "   {\r\n" + 
                "      \"projectkey\":\"proj1\"\r\n" + 
                "   },\r\n" + 
                "   {\r\n" + 
                "      \"projectkey\":\"proj2\"\r\n" + 
                "   },\r\n" + 
                "   {\r\n" + 
                "      \"projectkey\":\"proj3\"\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "]";
        JSONArray  array = new JSONArray(json);
        for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
            Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                String key = iterator.next();
                System.out.println("Key :: "+key+"  value :: "+jsonObject.getString(key));
            }           
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
Key :: projectkey  value :: proj1
Key :: projectkey  value :: proj2
Key :: projectkey  value :: proj3
```

Comment: hello, thank you for help but am trying to read json data which will be directly generated through database and will be saved in text file as shown earlier. m facing an error with parsing with the code I posted which is uanble to detect {,[," . My ultimate goal is to generate QR codes for multiple Json objects which are going to generated dynamically in database and then fetched in textfile.

Comment: post some data of ur text file, i can try something out for u.